# Relational database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, relational-database

I'm making a fantasy soccer team web application to learn how to use ruby on rails and I'm a bit confused regarding how relational databases should work with this sort of example.

I have a table for Users, Players, Teams and My_Team.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
    has_one :team
    has_and_belongs_to_many :my_team 
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :players
end

class MyTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :players
end
```

These are the models I've made. I'm wondering if I need a new class to tie them all together?
I'm not quite sure how to link them - I haven't made anything requiring a relational database model in a while!

I've successfully displayed all the data, and I have some dummy date in place for players and teams but how should I carry on so that one user has one user team, which has many players?

Is this right?

I'm trying to add a player to someones personal team but I feel like it's not working because of the table design..

Comment: Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm trying to add a player to someone's personal team but I feel like
>   it's not working because of the table design

`ob264` is somewhat right:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :teams
   has_many :players, through: :teams
end

#app/models/team.rb
Class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | user_id | other | team | details | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user

   has_many :player_teams
   has_many :players, through: :player_teams
end

#app/models/player.rb
Class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields id | team_id | other | team | details | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :player_teams
   has_many :teams, through: :player_teams
end

#app/models/player_team.rb
Class PlayerTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :player
end
```

This will allow you to create the following setup:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :teams #-> domain.com/teams/5/edit

#app/controllers/players_controller.rb
Class TeamsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
       @team = Team.find params[:id]
       @team.player_teams.build
   end

   def update
       @team = Team.find params[:id]
       @team.update(team_params)
   end

   private

   def team_params
      params.require(:team).permit(:team, :params, player_teams_attributes: [:player_id, :team_id])
   end
end
```

Although this will need tweaking, it will basically give you the ability to do this:

```
#app/views/teams/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @team do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :player_teams do |pt| %>
      <%= pf.collection_select :player_id, Player.all, :id, :name %> #-> adds a player to your team
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

**ActiveRecord Associations**

To answer your question more deeply, you have to appreciate the role of ActiveRecord associations that Rails uses. ActiveRecord is an ["ORM" (Object Relational Mapper)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) layer for data-driven applications, allowing the application-layer to build associated objects together.

The difference here is that if you want to create "relations" / "associations" in your dataset, you have to do several important things:

> 1. You need to appreciate the role of `foreign_keys` in your data tables
> 2. You need to associate your models correctly
> 3. You need to work at *object* level

Firstly, you need to appreciate that ActiveRecord is not magic - it build objects based off the **[`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)** in your data tables. This is typically a reference to the `primary_key` of the parent object:

[image]

This means that every time you build an association in Rails, you need to back it up with the data table `foreign_keys` it needs to find the respective data.

Secondly, you need to then ensure your models are associated correctly. The examples provided are a sufficient demonstration of how this should work (simple once you get your head around it!)

Thirdly, you need to the **appreciate working at *object level***. This is very important - Rails (as it's built on Ruby) is an [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) framework, meaning that *everything* you do is based around objects (which are constructed through the `Model`s, from the database)

I am saying this because the way I built the methodology for you above is *object orientated* -- you're wanting to update a user's "Team" object by adding / removing players from the association. This is a very important pattern to realize within Rails - it will help you profusely if you appreciate how it works

Answer (score 4):

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team 
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :players
    belongs_to :user
end

class User< ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :team
    has_many :players, through: :team
end
```

This structure allows each user to have a team which has many players

It also allows you to access each of the elements by

get users team: `@user.team`

get teams user: `@team.user`

get users players: `@user.players`

get players user: `@player.user`

get teams players: `@team.players`

get players team: `@player.team`

Hope this helps